# How to scroll text inside tabel cell

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How do I move the text inside a table cell?

For example:

```
<asp:TabelCell>XXXXX<asp:TabelCell>
```

...on scroll which appears on setting `overflow:scroll` for the `<asp:table>`??

Comment: @hari: Don't be mad about people down-voting your question. We'd like to help, but you have to put some effort in clearly defining your problem. What you've written is obviously misunderstood. **Try to clearly define your problem**.

Comment: @hari: you should ask a new question and not completely rewrite an old and long overdue (and closed) question...

Answer (score 2):

### Scrolling is client-side functionality

This doesn't have anything to do with server-side code (in your case Asp.net WebForms) but rather with client side CSS settings.

Set your cell's style to `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;` and it will scroll its content accordingly.

To avoid inline styles I would also suggest to give your table cell a CSS class on the server side. This has several benefits:

- no inline styles - better maintainability
- no `#id` bound CSS selectors
- re-usability of the same functionality to several elements on various pages

Code in your ASPX should look like:

```
<asp:TableCell CssClass="scroll-content">XXXXXX</asp:TableCell>
```

then have it defined in your CSS file as:

```
.scroll-content
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: no i just want to move a particular cell text along with scroll bar movement

Comment: @harivenkatesh: You're not making yourself clear then... Try to define your question to be correctly understood... Which scrollbar are you referring to? Main browser window's scrollbar or table cell's scrollbar? If referring to latter than my solution works. But if you'd like to scroll some table cell's content when moving page's scrollbar that is a completely different problem that definitely doesn't offer any simple solution if any at all...

Comment: if(this.jGrid.attr("style").indexOf("height") != -1 || this.jGrid.attr("style").indexOf("HEIGHT") != -1)

how to optimize this statement? using regex how can this be optimized?